# Show real time wget output in a web page

Tags: php, bash, shell

I'm calling a shell script using **shell_exec** function of **php** where I'm downloading a file **from another server to the server** where this php page is hosted using **wget** command and sending a report to my page after completing the process. It works fine.

Here is my `TestFile.php` file

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec("sudo /home/user/myScript");
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

And my bash script `myScript`

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo wget -O /path/to/download/downloadfile http://example.com/TestFile.zip
```

But **I want to show the real time progress** of the wget operation on the webpage from where I'm calling the shell script. I want to show just the real time progress in percentage. On this way I'm able to send the progress of wget just in percentage to the webpage using this command

```
sudo wget -O /path/to/download/downloadfile http://example.com/TestFile.zip 2>&1 | grep -o "[0-9]\+%"
```

And, The output is like this

```
2%
4%
6%
8%
...
...
...
95%
97%
99%
100%
```

But this output is coming after completing the process. At the time of the process running the window doesn't show anything. But I don't want this.

I want the real time update of the process at the time of **wget** process running not after completing the command.
Could any one help me to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Can't test it at the moment but something like this should work:

```
<?php

ob_start();

$descriptors = [
    ['pipe', 'r'],
    ['pipe', 'w'],
    ['pipe', 'w'],
];

$process = proc_open('wget blahblah', $descriptors, $pipes, '/tmp', []);

if(is_resource($process)) {
    while ($line = fgets($pipes[1])) {
        echo $line;
        ob_flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I'm calling a shell script from the php page. Not running any shell command from the page. How can I get the progress using this php calling? @Igor Pantović As I'm not good at php that's why I can't get your answer. I've also checked [php doc](http://bd1.php.net/proc_open) here. But still I couldn't get. Please help.

Comment: First argument of `proc_open` is the shell command you want to run. Just like if you were using bash directly.

Comment: Is that mean I can run a bash script using `proc_open` function. As I'm saving a file from one server to another server then I must run a shell script not just a command. I tried the procedure above but I can't complete it.

Comment: You can. Provided that your server allows it. Many servers disallow it though because of security concerns.